# Vue - Emitting a data object but changing one changes them all

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a TODO app and want to pass by props from one component to another an array of objects. An object is added every time you click a button but I'm having trouble with it. The problem is that the property value becomes the same for every single object added to the array. It seems like it's not saving correctly each `tareas.tarea` data.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Header></Header>
    <AgregarTarea @tareaAgregada="agregarTarea"></AgregarTarea>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
          <Lista :tareas = 'tareas' @eliminarItem="eliminarTarea"></Lista>
          <!-- here i pass through props the array of objects -->
        </div>
        <div class="column">  
          <TareaFinalizada></TareaFinalizada>
          {}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Header from './components/Header'
import AgregarTarea from './components/AgregarTarea'
import Lista from './components/Lista'
import TareaFinalizada from './components/TareaFinalizada'

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      tareas:[]
    }
  },
  components: {
    Header,
    AgregarTarea,
    Lista,
    TareaFinalizada
  },
  methods: {
    agregarTarea(data){
     //add new object to the array
      this.tareas.push(data)
    },
    eliminarTarea(data) {
      this.tareas.splice(data.id, 1);
    }
  }

};
</script>
```

AgregarTarea.vue || Here is where i add a new ToDo

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input" v-model="tareas.tarea">
        <button class="button is-primary" @click="agregarTarea">Agregar Tarea</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data(){
        return {
            tareas: {
                tarea:'',
                id:null,
                editar:false
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        agregarTarea(){
            this.$emit('tareaAgregada', this.tareas)
            this.tareas.tarea = ' ';
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

Lista.vue || And here is where i display the ToDo's

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="list is-hoverable">
            <ul>
                <li v-for="(tarea, index) in tareas" :key="index">
                    <a class="list-item has-text-centered" @click="editarTexto(index)">
                        {{ tarea }}
                        <div class="editar" v-if="editar">
                            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Text input" v-model="nuevaTarea">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <button class="button is-danger" @click="eliminarItem(index)">Eliminar</button>
                    <div><input type="checkbox"> Finalizada</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props:['tareas'],
    data(){
        return {
            nuevaTarea: ' ',
            editar:false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        eliminarItem(index){
            this.$emit('eliminarItem', index)
        },
        editarTexto(){
            this.editar = true
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript objects are passed by reference (not cloned by value). Each time you `$emit` the `tareas` object from *AgregarTarea.vue*, it's the same object reference as before, even if the properties have changed.  So all of the objects in your `tareas` array in *App.vue* are the same object.

To fix this, change *AgregarTarea.vue* to `$emit` a clone each time:

```js
methods: {
    agregarTarea(){
        this.$emit('tareaAgregada', Object.assign({}, this.tareas)) // clone
        this.tareas.tarea = ' ';
    }
}
```

(This is a shallow clone and would not work properly if `this.tareas` had nested objects, but it doesn't.)

---

## Option #2

Here's a different way that works easily for nested objects:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return {
      tareas: null  // <-- It's not filled here
    }
  },
  methods: {
    resetTareas() { // <-- it's filled here instead
      this.tareas = {
        tarea:'',
        id:null,
        editar:false
      }
    },
    agregarTarea(){
      this.$emit('tareaAgregada', this.tareas);
      this.resetTareas(); // <-- Create a brand new object after emitting
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.resetTareas();  // <-- This is for the first one
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Tarea: <input type="text" v-model="tareas.tarea" /><br /><br />
  <button @click="agregarTarea">Emit</button><br /><br />
  Object: {{ tareas }}
</div>
```

Since `resetTareas` creates a brand new object every time, you don't have to worry about cloning anything, and it works even if `tareas` is a complex nested object.

Comment: I knew that was happening! but didnt know how to resolve it. Thank you so much!, is there a propper way to resolve this problem?

Comment: You're welcome! There is a proper way, you're looking at it :) I edited my answer to show another way too.  It might be superior in some situations and it works for nested objects as well.